# Combined several javascripts into single .js file, now having conflicting onload functions

Tags: javascript, function, conflict, onload-event

Good Afternoon

I'm experiencing an issue where I have three scripts - a URL Force, a script that passes a certain variable and finally a really great IE Placeholder script that I found here on StackOverflow.

When I had all the script in separate files, the IE Placeholder script was working.

Then a realized the other two scripts weren't getting called so I did an onload call in the body tag

```
onload="onLoad(); switchToHTTPS();"
```

When I did that however, the IE Form fix stopped working.  so now I think I have a conflict of onload functions.  So to help clean things up I combined all the different scripts into a single one

http://jsfiddle.net/qtmvL/1/

How can I get each script to automatically run when the page loads? and not have any conflicts?

Comment: what the error message raised on IE? are both onload and switchToHTTPS global function or they live in some namespace or nested scopes?

Comment: Great question, I don't know 50% of what you asked me - I'm a very weak javascript programmer

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would suggest is to introduce some closure. You have everything set in the global scope, but I would recommend separating things out into their own scope.

Take a look here. http://jsfiddle.net/2YGtz/

The basic idea here is we're going to break each section out and have each of them return a "onload" function

```
var ieFix = (function () {
    var load = function () {
        //Do your load operations here...
    };

    return {
        //Return your ieFix onload function so it can be accessed in the global scope
        onLoad: load
    };

})(); //Note the parens here. This will execute the function right away, which will
      //declare and return the onload function right away, so you can access it when
      //when you declare your "window.onload" function below.

var passVar = (function () {
    var load = function () {
        //Do your passVar load operations here
    };

    return {
        //Return your passVar onload function
        onLoad: load
    };
})();
//Create a combined "window.onload" function now.
window.onload = function () {
    ieFix.load();
    passVar.load();
};
```

Look at the comments I made, and note the descriptions on the various declarations of the variable x.

**Second edit**

```
$(document).load(function () {
    //Load function here...
})
```

The nice thing about the $(document).load() method, is every time you pass a function in, it adds it to the onload function rather than overwriting the function, and if the onload event has already fired, it'll just call the function right away. So rather than returning the load functions, you can just do a

```
$(document).load(function () { //load stuff })
```

right in the closure function.

Comment: Hmm, the IEform fix appears to be working, the http to https force no longer works please help

Comment: What's the error that you're seeing? Could you post a new link to js fiddle with what you're currently working on?

Comment: the error i see in the console is ReferenceError: load is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

onLoad: load

Comment: I'm looking through the code again and I'm not seeing anything. Two things to check.

First, are you sure you're not overwriting the window.onload event somewhere else?

And Second, are you sure there isn't another error before that's preventing the self executing function creating the scope from completing successfully, thus causing the onLoad member to not be defined?

Comment: no other then some javascript validation there's no other javascript being called except for the standard jquery.js file

Comment: if you're using jQuery, then you can use jQuery to add on load events. Check the example in my edit.

Comment: can you combine javascript syntax and jquery?  also, whgere would I put $(document).load(function () { }); ?

Comment: this isn't working, none of the scripts are being called.  I'll have to abandon this method I think.

Comment: try replacing load with ready. $(document).ready(function () {});